# Коммунальный мост: прописная или строчная?

Tags: прописная, строчная, названия

В моем городе (как и в 4 других в России) есть т.н. коммунальный мост. "Вики" определяет КМ как "автомобильно-пешеходный мост" через определенную реку, то есть по сути это имя нарицательное, слово "коммунальный" раскрывает функцию моста (поскольку в Перми через Каму построен и железнодорожный мост, название которого никому не приходит в голову писать с прописной). Но существует также еще один мост - Красавинский, и он тоже автомобильно-пешеходный. В этом случае получается, что по аналогии "коммунальный" - это имя собственное.

С другой стороны, повторюсь, я предполагаю, что имя собственное должно быть относительно уникальным,а  наличие коммунальных мостов в 5 городах России как-то эту уникальность снимает.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, считать ли в данном случае КМ именем собственным или нарицательным?

Добавлено: мост имеет и другое название - Камский. Кроме того, долгое время существовало только 2 моста - коммунальный и ж/д, Красавинский появился значительно позже и получил особое название, как я понимаю, для того, чтобы отличать его от Камского.

Answer (score 1):

Вы должны прежде всего свериться у местных топонимистов, кто, как и когда присвоил название мосту. "Коммунальный" вполне может оказаться именем собственным по какой-то прихоти чиновников. Если такого нет, то очевидно, что Камский - это название, а "коммунальный" - назначение и требует строчной буквы.

Answer (score 0):

Мост должен иметь название: оно используется в речи, отмечается на картах. Если его называют Коммунальным, то это будет имя собственное, просто в данном случае оно совпадает с нарицательным словом *коммунальный*.

В качестве похожего примера можно привести названия рек, например  название реки Дон: слово *дон* по-осетински означает «река» или «вода».

Также другие примеры: [ГОЛУБЫЕ ДОРОГИ | nplit.ru](http://nplit.ru/books/item/f00/s00/z0000047/st009.shtml)

Comment: Какой смысл в примерах, если все городские топонимы по сврему уникальны и даются не иначе как через постановления топонимической комиссии местным органом законодательной власти? Зачем гадать на кофейной гуще, если можно установить наверняка?

Comment: Никто не гадает,  я начинаю ответ следующим  образом: "Мост должен иметь название: оно используется в речи, отмечается на картах". Информация о том, что его называют Камским, добавлена позже.

Comment: Я про это: *Если его называют Коммунальным, то это будет имя собственное,*

Comment: Это топоним и если используется как топоним в текущем контексте (тип имени собственного), то будет писаться с большой буквы. Официальный ли это топоним или нет, уже другой вопрос. Можно сказать что " местные называют его Коммунальный мостом".